# (Outlook 2010) Getting mail headers in C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I've adapted Ken Slovak's code from [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/getting-headers-mailitem-t2635914.html) to read MailItem headers on a message before it is sent, but my header string is coming up as empty.  Does this only work on received messages?  If so, what would be a good method for pulling in the headers of the original message before composing Forward/Reply/Reply-To-All?

Here is my re-done code:

```
        Outlook.PropertyAccessor oPA = msg.PropertyAccessor as Outlook.PropertyAccessor;
        const string PR_MAIL_HEADER_TAG = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E";
        try
        {
            string strHeaders = (string)oPA.GetProperty(PR_MAIL_HEADER_TAG);
        }
        catch { }
```

Thanks

Comment: @aloneguid - I should have specified I was working in 2010.  PA has only been in existence since 2007

Answer (score 1):

The message headers will only be populated once the original message has been sent. I tried your code and it returned the message headers for mail that I had received. I did get the security popup when trying to access the message though.

Comment: thanks, I had a feeling about that.  What I'm trying to accomplish is to get the headers from the parent messages to determine if/how the rest of the add-in should work.

Comment: Could you explain a little more about your add-in and what you are  trying to achieve please?

Comment: I was trying to read attachment information from the parent message prior to forwarding to see if certain actions should take place.